# Stop running code (end program) after command start

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to create a file that opens a specified link on the default browser (either Google Chrome or Edge) of the computer running it. First I tried with a batch file:

```
start https://www.example.com/
```

But it flashes the console so I made a VBScript file to hide it:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "test.bat", 0
```

But I only wanted 1 file so I changed it to:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd /c start https://www.example.com/", 0
```

Now it does what I want. The only problem I found is that apparently it doesn't end the process (doesn't stop running) until I close the opened browser.

If I run it and leave the browser open I can delete the file but not the directory/folder. I get a error saying that it's not possible because the folder or a file in it is opened in another program.

Adding the `exit` command didn't solved the issue too.

I don't know much of DOS commands/batch files nor VBScript.

Comment: A file which opens a URL in the default browser usually has the file extension `.url`! I see no reason if you're going down the `VBScript` route, not to use something like this: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("https://www.example.com")`

Comment: @Compo I checked that out and it might indeed be a better way of doing it. With `[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://stackoverflow.com` and saving with the `.url` extension. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call it instead of batch?

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "iexplore http://www.stackoverflow.com", 0
```

Comment: "First I tried with a batch file: `start https://www.example.com/` But it flashes the console so I made a VBScript file to hide it"

Comment: And that also doesn't solve the problem explained in the end of my question.

Comment: @user7393973 ok, so which process do you to want to exit? the vbscript?

Comment: I think it's the batch code. To test what I mean create a folder, make a file with `start "" https://www.example.com`, open it (tested on Google Chrome, IE seems to not get the issue), don't close the browser and try to delete the test folder where the file is.

Comment: I'm not asking how to delete the folder with code, I'm saying that the simple command `start` leaves the program still running until I close the opened browser even if I add `exit`.

Comment: @user7393973 ok, try the edit please. you should be getting vbscript to exit and be able to manually delete the folder.

Comment: It works with iexplore but not google chrome for some reason.

Comment: how do you launch the chrome one? `chrome  http://www.stackoverflow.com` ?

Comment: Yes. Both using `chrome` or just the `start` command (since Chrome is my default browser) do the same.